# JavaScript delete object property gives error when it is not in quotes

Tags: javascript

```
let person = {
    firstName : 'John',
    lastName : 'Doe',
    123 : 'test'
}

delete person['lastName']; //deletes
delete person[lastName]; // gives error
delete person.lastname; // deletes
delete person[123]; // deletes
```

lastName and 123 are both Strings but why to delete person[lastName] gives me an error.

Can you explain the delete command in detail?

Thanks

Comment: It's not about the delete command, it's about the basic syntax rules for referencing object properties in general.

Comment: you can not delete property like this , delete person[lastName], lastName this means this is variable and have some value,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable

Comment: Neither `123` nor `lastName` are strings. `'lastName'` is a string (a string literal that evaluates to a string). `123` is a number literal that evaluates to a number. `lastName` is a variable reference that evaluates to an error because there’s no variable with the name `lastName`. Think of the part in brackets as being like any other expression that you might find outside of brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you get is "lastName is not defined", which should point you in the right direction already.

If you use `person[lastName]` then you are referring to an index on your person object with the same value as the value of the variable `lastName`. That variable doesn't exist, hence the error.

Add `let lastName = 'lastName'` before your 4 lines of delete in your code and you will see that it works as expected, and then try to understand why this works :)

Answer (score 0):

`person[lastName]` is a *property access* using *bracket notation*. See the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) about this:

> In the `object[property_name]` syntax, the property_name is just a string or Symbol.

So what you put in the brackets must be a string or Symbol. If it's not one of those, it will be evaluated and coerced to a string. You're providing just, `lastName` - this is not a string literal or Symbol, so the interpreter thinks you want to supply a variable with a string value. But `lastName` is not a defined variable, hence you get the error `lastName is not defined`.

This behavior is not specific to the delete operator in any way. You'd get an error attempting this property access in any context - in assignment, passing arguments, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is lastName is a variable when used in brackets [] and not in quotes.

So, when you refer lastName using dot notation, you are referring to a property of the object `object.lastName`, but when you use `object[lastName]`, you are saying that give me the value of a property from the object whose key is the same as the value of lastName.

Your understanding of the delete command is correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
delete person['lastName']; //here 'lastName' is the key you access from person
delete person[lastName];   //here lastName is a variable which is `undefined` in your caseand try, it will work
```

If you want this code to work, declare a variable `lastName`

```
let lastName = 'lastName';
let person = {
    firstName : 'John',
    lastName : 'Doe',
    123 : 'test'
}

delete person['lastName']; //deletes
delete person[lastName]; // this will not give error
delete person.lastname; // deletes
delete person[123]; // deletes
```